# DWR request success

Tags: java, ajax, dwr

Is there any way I can understand when the dwr jax request is completed?

```
callback : function(data) {
                updateData(arg1, arg2);
                showData();
            }
```

Comment: I'd guess it's when the data display is complete.

Comment: but is there something like 'onSucess' ?